# Create tables in Flask with one model.py file for each Blueprint

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a flask app with two blueprints, i am register the bluprints like this:

```
app.register_blueprint(users, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(rooms, url_prefix='/rooms')
```

Each blueprint has its own templates folder, views.py file and models.py file.
What i need to do to create the database tables described in each models.py and give the database with initial data like The user admin and roles?

I am thinking in a separate script that imports all the models and finally invoke db.create_all() method but i don't know about a better way to do what i need.

I expect the tabled created, later the initial data in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a [boilerplate](https://github.com/yoann9344/flask-boilerplate) that might describe what you need.

Comment: I see, In your repo;  the manage.py file import db and later invoke the method db.create_all(), in my case i have the models in different folders, so, is more convenient to have all  the models in the same folder?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, for me it is more readable to split models in many folders. I don't think it really matters, that's just how you prefer to organize your project ?